# text appears in limited width even after using wrap_content

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, textview

I have set width of all the components to wrap_content in MainActivity but `wrap_content` does not works, I mean when I type into `EditText` then text appears only in limited width.

I want the `TextViews` and `EditTexts` to expand their widths according to input text length.

Please help, what is issue with my code?

**MainActivity XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.appdeveloper.appname.MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff003b"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:src="@drawable/applogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="You Can&apos;t Proceed Without Inserting Primary Sim (SIM-1) In Your Device!"
        android:id="@+id/regNoSim_id"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="REGISTRATION"
        android:id="@+id/regTitle_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginPassword_id"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regName_id"
                android:hint="Your Name"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regPassword_id"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regName_id"
                android:hint="Application Password"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regVerifyPass_id"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regPassword_id"
                android:hint="Verify Password"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regRingCode_id"
                android:hint="Ringing Codeword"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regVerifyPass_id"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regLocationCode_id"
                android:hint="Location Codeword"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regRingCode_id"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regNum1_id"
                android:hint="1st Trusted Number"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regLocationCode_id"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regNum2_id"
                android:hint="2nd Trusted Number"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regNum1_id"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regNum3_id"
                android:hint="3rd Trusted Number"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regNum2_id"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/regEmail_id"
                android:hint="Email Address"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regNum3_id"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Register"
                android:id="@+id/regButton_id"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regEmail_id"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword_id"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="Enter Application Password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appLogoImage_id"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Forgotten Password?"
        android:id="@+id/forgottenPass_id"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginPassword_id"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you need the EditText to fill the screen width?
What is your requirement now, can you add a sample image

Comment: why both text view is below image view . shouldn't it overlap each other?

Comment: @Sajal Ali check my answer it will work nicely ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have set  `android:ems="10"` and that's the limitation remove it and see the difference!

You are thinking it's wrapped and adjust it's size  because of your `wrap_content` but you have set `android:ems` !

> Makes the `TextView` be exactly this many ems wide.

Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ems